# CodenameOne to VueJS back and forth communication

Tags: javascript, java, vuejs2, codenameone

We have a web app build in Vue JS and it's SPA, now we want mobile version of the app but due to time and other factors we don't want to build the mobile app from scratch so we resort to using CodenameOne BrowserComponent to load the web app and because it's CodenameOne we can submit to app stores.

The issue we're have now is that the app will have phonebook contacts access on the mobile device, CodenameOne have full access to mobile device once the user grant the permission but reading the contacts in CodenameOne and sending it to VueJs component that will display it is where our issue lie.

CodenameOne can interact with Javascript but I've not seen sample codes for VueJs.

Comment: I haven't worked with VueJS but I don't understand how this would be different  from other JS code. You can just invoke a JS function which will invoke the vueJS code. What am I missing here?

Comment: We used NPM and Webpack to build and bundle the assets that's where I have a little confusion on interacting with Javascript codes bundled using Webpack from Java in CodenameOne.

Comment: It's still JavaScript under the hood and you should be able to post a message to it using the post message API https://www.codenameone.com/blog/post-message.html

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, thanks for the pointer, as long as the JavaScript object or function is attached to the browser window object it will be accessible from CodenameOne (Java) or JavaScript. Tried some tests and thay are working fine.